# Execute a command if another one was succesfull?

Tags: c#, mysql, database, visual-studio-2012

I am working with the MySQL-Connector/Net.

How can i assure, that a Command has really been executed.
Does it work like this or does it not work like that?

I want the Command inside the if just to be executed, if the first command
was succesfull, because the 2nd command is updating Stats.

I need that for an sqlcommand and for an sql_adapter update and fill command.

```
if (sql_command.ExecuteNonQuery() != 0)
{
    sql_command2.ExecuteNonQuery();
}

if (sql_adapter.Fill(dataSet, "Entry") != 0)
{
    sql_command2.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: the first way is the right way. ExecuteNonQuery will return -1 if it wasnt successful.

Comment: @Relax I don't think that's correct. `ExecuteNonQuery` returns the number of rows affected. It will return 0 if none, or if the query errors, it will throw an exception.

Comment: @RGraham See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery%28v=vs.110%29.aspx Quote:"For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, the return value is the number of rows affected by the command. When a trigger exists on a table being inserted or updated, the return value includes the number of rows affected by both the insert or update operation and the number of rows affected by the trigger or triggers. For all other types of statements, the return value is -1. If a rollback occurs, the return value is also -1."

Comment: so it should be for the first one > 0 or ? Else the 2nd command would be also executed, because -1 is != 0 and what about the sql_adapter.fill?

Comment: @Relax Good spot, thanks.

Comment: @user3438236 Thats true but the first one is the better one for me ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following:

```
if (sql_command.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0)
{
    sql_command2.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

The ExecuteNonQuery returns the number of records affected. (by the command itself and any associated triggers)

If your definition of a successful command1 is **`some`** records getting updated, so that you run the command2 for updating the stats, the above code is enough.

If your definition of a successful command1 is it running `**without**` any errors (irrespective of the records updated) use this:

```
sql_command.ExecuteNonQuery();
sql_command2.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

This is because the ExecuteNonQuery will return 0 if no records are affected and can also return -1 on certain successful executions, when `**SET NOCOUNT ON**` is encounted in the query/stored procedure. (-1 is also returned on rollbacks etc.)

Comment: does it also work with the sql_adapter fill and update command?

Answer (score 0):

Use try/catch to see any exceptions:

```
try { sql_command.ExecuteNonQuery(); }
catch { MessageBox.Show("The first SQL command failed"); }
sql_command2.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Read more about the `SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()` exceptions here:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Ashton, You cannot have code betwen try and catch like that? read more about C# syntax?